# VB6 control support Unicode while running through code but not while debugging?

Tags: debugging, encoding, vb6, unicode-string

I have a Text box in vb6, that would display the Unicode characters when running though exe, but when running through code(debug mode), this is show junk characters.

I know not all built-in Vb controls support Unicode. what could be the cause?

As of now i am using VB6 Fusion approach to support Unicode character, is there a better option to provide the support?

Comment: "not all built-in Vb controls support Unicode" is not true. In fact all built-in VB6 controls don't support Unicode.

Comment: This question might be helpful [How to display Unicode text in VB6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540361/whats-the-best-option-to-display-unicode-text-hebrew-etc-in-vb6)

Comment: @wqw command button, option button etc.,,do support Unicode, but the point of concern is in one of the application the text box is supporting the unicode when running the exe but not when debugging. please change your system locale then it will display this behaviour

Comment: @sandeephu: Changing system locale is the opposite of unicode support. I'm native Bulgarian, i'm dealing with Cyrillic code page everyday.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 IDE as well as most of controls does not support unicode. If you set apropriate default system regional(Japanesse?) setting you should see characters correctly.