# VB6 application requires Office/Visual Basic installation for Hebrew support

Tags: deployment, vb6, hebrew

I'm trying to make an old VB6 application work.
In one of it's document the previous programmer wrote that it need an Office installation for Hebrew support.
Without Office or Visual Basic installed the Hebrew shows without RTL.

Any ideas on what causes the problem?

Here are my project file's references:

```
Object={C0A63B80-4B21-11D3-BD95-D426EF2C7949}#1.0#0; VSFLEX7L.OCX
Reference=*\G{8C344710-5FEC-11CF-A0BF-00AA0062BE57}#1.0#0#..\..\..\WINDOWS\SysWow64\MSCDRUN.DLL#Microsoft Connection Designer Instance 1.0
Reference=*\G{EE008642-64A8-11CE-920F-08002B369A33}#2.0#0#..\..\..\WINDOWS\SysWow64\MSRDO20.DLL#Microsoft Remote Data Object 2.0
Reference=*\G{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#2.0#0#..\..\..\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb#OLE Automation
Object={BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}#1.1#0; TABCTL32.OCX
Object={3B7C8863-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}#1.2#0; RICHTX32.OCX
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; MSCOMCTL.OCX
Object={0BA686C6-F7D3-101A-993E-0000C0EF6F5E}#1.0#0; THREED32.OCX
Object={F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}#1.2#0; COMDLG32.OCX
Object={648A5603-2C6E-101B-82B6-000000000014}#1.1#0; MSCOMM32.OCX
Object={6FBA474E-43AC-11CE-9A0E-00AA0062BB4C}#1.0#0; SYSINFO.OCX
Object={5E9E78A0-531B-11CF-91F6-C2863C385E30}#1.0#0; MSFLXGRD.OCX
Object={C932BA88-4374-101B-A56C-00AA003668DC}#1.1#0; MSMASK32.OCX
```

Comment: Educated guess is that the previous programmer used Forms 2.0 to enable Visual Basic 6 to display Unicode characters. Eek! 

There's a bit more under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540361/whats-the-best-option-to-display-unicode-text-hebrew-etc-in-vb6). I believe Forms 2.0 is not legally redistributable and I believe can cause your app to crash.

Comment: @MarkJ Can't see it in References or Components so I guess it's not the issue, but it might be related.

Comment: Please post your vbp file or just the lines starting with words Reference and Object from vbp file.

Comment: Not seeing it in Reference or Component could also mean it's late-bound in code. Have you done a text search for `CreateObject`.

Comment: So a bit of an update. Hebrew does work now, but it doesn't support RTL if no office installed.
I'll attach the vbp to the original question.